# Why HTML `<input type="file" />` accept property `audio/mpeg` and `audio/mp3` works the same if I just want to select MP3?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Please see these two minimum examples

## audio/mpeg

```html
<input type="file" accept="audio/mpeg">
```

## audio/mp3

```html
<input type="file" accept="audio/mp3">
```

Both examples can select the only MP3, why is this happening?

If I want to force my user to just select an MP3 file, which code snippet should I use?

Which one is the best?

Answer (score 4):

An MP3 is just the audio portion of a MPEG file, so specifying `audio/mpeg` is equivalent to specifying `audio/mp3`.

More info about media formats can be found [in this article on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers)